# Plot in Matlab using loaded image instead of default point options

Tags: image, matlab, graph, scatter

I would like to make a scatter in Matlab using a custom image as a representation of a data point instead of the default available options. Is this possible, and if so, how can I make it happen?

Comment: You mean like a smilie-face as a data point instead of a `'.'` or `'*'`?.

Comment: Mathematica might have an easier interface for doing this, but you could try this if you must stick with matlab: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/12650). Edit, these also [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1AS2T/?product=ML&solution=1-1AS2T) that @chappjc was referring to.

Comment: I was also thinking about [this submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39487-custom-marker-plot) for shapes specified by coordinate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The mathworks forum seems to say this is not straightforward to do [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/32985-can-i-make-a-scatterplot-with-custom-marker-symbols).

You can use characters from the wingdings font, but not with the scatter command itself.

You could also use the image command, but you would need to have enough pixels to render your images. This could lead to a larger than necessary file size.

You might want to try exporting your data to another programme. It seems that excel could acheive this for [you](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120227034654AAw4euE)